# Stubbing out method with ArrayList/List param fails when using any() or anyList()

Tags: java, testing, mockito, spy

I have a java class.

```
class Blah{
        public Blah(){

        }
        public String testMe(List<String> s){
            return new String("hello "+s.get(0));
        }


        public String testMeString(String s){
            return new String("hello "+s);
        }


    }
```

I am unable trying to stub and test the testMe method successfully. Note that I am just trying to understand mocking in java. For example I have tried:

```
    @Test
    public void testTestMe(){
        Blah blah = spy(new Blah());
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("oopsie");
        when(blah.testMe(Matchers.any())).thenReturn("intercepted");
        assertEquals("intercepted",blah.testMe(l));
```

This returns a NullPointerException. I have also tried any(List.class), any(ArrayList.class). I have also tried using `anyList()` but this gives me an IndexOutOfBounds error. What am I doing wrong?
Interestingly, my `testMeString` works fine. If I do

```
@Test
    public void testTestMeString(){
        Blah blah = spy(new Blah());
        when(blah.testMeString(any())).thenReturn("intercepted");
        assertEquals("intercepted",blah.testMeString("lala"));
}
```

the tests pass with any() and any(String.class).

Comment: Wait, which method is your system under test? If you're testing `testMe` then why are you trying to spy `testMe`?

Comment: Good Question, I am trying to understand how spying + when + thenReturn works. Let me clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NullPointerException is being thrown during your *stubbing*, not during your test.

This is because `Matchers.any()` actually returns `null`, so if you use it when you're calling a real method, you pass `null` as the argument. `testMeString` happens to work because `null + s` doesn't cause a NullPointerException (the string `"null"` is used instead).

Instead of:

```
when(blah.testMe(any())).thenReturn("intercepted");
```

You need to use

```
doReturn("intercepted").when(blah).testMe(any());
```

This is documented (although admittedly not super clearly) as the [Important gotcha on spying real objects!](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) in the Mockito documentation.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Daniel was first so I will mark him as correct answer although all answers seem to be similar.

Answer (score 3):

With this statement `blah.testMe()` includes in the `when()`, it invokes the real method :

```
when(blah.testMe(Matchers.any())).thenReturn("intercepted");
```

To avoid that, you should use the `doReturn(...).when(...).methodToInvoke()` pattern.

```
doReturn("intercepted").when(blah).testMe(Matchers.any()));
```

You notice that with this syntax : the `blah.testMe()` statement is specified nowhere. So that is not called.

Beyond this question I think you don't need any spy to test this method.
Spying is a very particular tool in mocking that you use only when you don't have any choice : you need to mock the object under test which is a bad practice and you cannot refactor the actual code.

But here you can just do :

```
@Test
public void testTestMe(){
    Blah blah = new Blah();
    ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("oopsie");
    assertEquals("hello oopsie",blah.testMe(l));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should reconsider using `spy`, `mock` etc. those facilities should be used when you have an external system, rest web service, DB you don't want to call during unit tests. In simple scenarios like this one just create some test input and check the output.

```
@Test public void testTestMeString(){
 //given
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa");
 //when
 String result = blah.testMe(list);
 //then
 assertEquals(result, "hello aaa");
 }
```

When you are interested in `given, when, then` check BDD.